# Do Something after a health check call on Kubernetes Pod

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, livenessprobe

I have a spring boot microservice running on K8s. I have configured liveness and readiness probes in my yaml file.

For my specific case I want to save a record in database with timestamps whenever the probes get executed in Kubernetes. How can I do this in Spring. Is there a listener kind of thing for this that listens for probe calls and take action based on that?

Comment: Please add the YAML where you configure the probes - that would make it easier to suggest a well-fitting solution.